# Population Growth Using Matrices (Population Transition Matrix?)

Tags: linear-algebra

I am very reluctant to ask this, as it feels like cheating, but I am truly stumped with this question (we haven't looked at any questions like these in the unit before). There are 7 parts to the question, but I'm hoping if I can get some hints to how to work out the first 2, I can figure out the rest.

"In a flock of wild Hoatzins, the females can be classified as being either chicks (up to 1 year old) or adults.
Each year, for every 100 adult females, 60 female chicks are born. Each year, about 60% of the chicks survive
to become adults and 90% of the adults survive. So, if at some point in time there were 100 female chicks
and 100 female adults, then, after a year there will be 60 female chicks, and 60 of the original chicks will have
survived to join the 90 surviving adults to give 150 female adults."

a) Write down equations for $c_{1}$ and $a_{1}$ in terms of $c_{0}$ and $a_{0}$ and express these equations in matrix form,
using a matrix A .

For this, I got $c_{1} = 0.6a_{0}$, and $a_{1} = 0.9a_{0}+0.6c_{0}$
Now I'm not exactly sure how to represent this in a matrix. I wrote:
$\begin{bmatrix}
 0&0.6 \\ 
 0.6&0.9 
\end{bmatrix}$

with column 1 being for $c_{0}$ and column 2 for $a_{0}$ but even then I'm pretty sure this is incorrect.

b) Use this to find a matrix equation that would enable you to calculate $c_{n}$ and $a_{n}$ from $c_{0}$ and $a_{0}$.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I've found the Leslie model, but it seems to function by knowing the maximum age of the Hoatzins. I'm only given that 90% of the adults survive each year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

$x_1 = A x_0$, $x_2 = A x_1 = A^2 x_0$ $\ldots$

$$
x_n = A^n x_0
$$

To solve this problem, note that if $A$ is diagonalizable $A = U\Lambda U^{-1}$ with $\Lambda = {\rm diag}\{\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\cdots\}$ then

$$
x_n = A^n x_0 = \underbrace{(U\Lambda U^{-1})(U\Lambda U^{-1})\cdots (U\Lambda U^{-1})}_{n~{\rm times}}x_0 = U\Lambda^n U^{-1}x_0
$$

with $\Lambda^n = {\rm diag}\{\lambda_1^n,\lambda_2^n,\cdots\}$

Comment: Ah I see, so this is how I would solve part b, finding a matrix equation that would enable me to calculate $c_{n}$ and $a_{n}$. So I just need to find my matrix A, then the eigenvalues finding eigenvectors $v_{1}$, and $v_{2}$ with this being my U($v_{1}$, $v_{2}$) and my diagonal matrix as you've stated above, the diagonals being my eigenvalues. But, I still am lost as to how I find the correct A to begin with.

But also, the other parts involve finding the eigenvalues of A. So if part B already involves finding the eigenvalues, doesn't it make it a bit redundant?

Comment: @Skylineblue The matrix $A$ is what you have already. As for the other parts, I wouldn't say redundant. If you found the eigenvalues alreaty, then solving then it is easy to answer them

Comment: Oh, so the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}
 0&0.6 \\ 
 0.6&0.9 
\end{bmatrix}$ is correct?

Comment: I figured it out! Thanks for your help! Part d) asks "For each eigenvalue λ , calculate |λ|." does this really just mean the absolute value of the eigenvalue? That seems a bit too simple and I'm wondering if I'm missing something

Comment: @Skylineblue In this case $\lambda_{1,2}\in \Bbb{R}$, to $|\lambda_{1,2}|$ is just the absolute value. Happy to help

Comment: Too easy! Thank you again. I've answered the rest of the parts of the question except one, and I've been looking at it for the better part of an hour now [link](https://gyazo.com/3b8d4417a38a189be64f97d7013dc4eb)  
(linking it because I am getting too tired to format it all). How should I approach this?

Comment: @Skylineblue will go offline now, but I will come back to you later tonight

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58715/discussion-between-skylineblue-and-caverac).

Comment: @Skylineblue If you call ${\bf u}_i$ the $i$-th eigenvector, then you can write it as ${\bf u}_1 = u_{11}{\bf \epsilon}_1 + u_{12}{\bf \epsilon}_2$ with a similar expression for ${\bf u}_2$, you can obtain the vectors ${\bf \epsilon}_i$ in terms of ${\bf u}_i$ (the relation is actually given by the matrix $U$ above), and the express any vector of the form ${\bf x} = a{\bf \epsilon}_1 + b{\bf \epsilon}_2$ as ${\bf x} = \alpha {\bf u}_1 + \beta {\bf u}_2$. I will leave the rest for you to work out the details. If you have further questions you should post them as a new question

Comment: I've written something based on this, and I'm going to go with it even though I'm not entirely sure it's correct. Thank you once again!